# The ratio of icons created with flutter_naitive_splash spreads horizontally

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the `flutter_naitive_splash` package to create a splash screen. However, for some reason, the image I set up is displayed on the screen with the image spread out horizontally on Android, while on IOS there is no problem.
How can I get Android to display a splash image while keeping the original image proportions?

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: assets/images/icons/icon.png 
  branding: assets/images/icons/branding.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  android_12:
    color: "#ffffff"
    image: assets/images/icons/icon_android.png
    branding: assets/images/icons/branding.png
```

Comment: can you screenshot the current result?

Comment: Why do you want to see the icon image?